# ¿Cuál es el número máximo de apps permitidas en una cuenta Google Play Console?

Tags: android, google-play

hace un momento pregunté en un grupo de AdMob (gente no tan experimentada) cuanto era lo máximo o recomendado de apps a tener en una cuenta en Google Play Console, y decían de 10 a 15, ¿esto es cierto?, ustedes en su experiencia, o en lo que Google dictamina, ¿cuánto es lo recomendable?

**Entiendo que la pregunta pueda resultar estúpida para muchos de ustedes, pero entiendan un poco, soy noob en esto, y la mayoría de ustedes ya son gente experiementada. De todas maneras, muchas gracias por pasar por acá.**

Comment: No hay número máximo definido, he visto cuentas con más de 250 aplicaciones!

Comment: Ya veo, también leí que al tener 2 apps suspendidas corres mucho riesgo, eso es cierto?

Comment: De hecho puedes tener solo una y si reincides en violar las políticas https://play.google.com/intl/es/about/developer-content-policy/ tu cuenta puede ser suspendida. @vonAlt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me atrevo a responder esta pregunta ya que en realidad hay una respuesta, y esta es que hasta el día de hoy Febrero 2020, **no hay numero máximo definido por Google para subir tus aplicaciones en [Google Play Console](https://developer.android.com/distribute/console?hl=es).**

Puedes subir la cantidad de aplicaciones que desees en  [Google Play Console](https://developer.android.com/distribute/console?hl=es)

pero hay algo que debes considerar, algunas aplicaciones que crees probablemente necesitaran credenciales ("OAuth Client IDs") para utilizar algunas API´s, las cuales puedes asignar en [**Google Could Platform - Credentials**](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/) por cada proyecto, me parece que son alrededor de 30 (¿?), por lo que si requieres una cantidad mayor necesitarías contactar a Google para que crean un mayor numero de slots.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]